# Which type of connection do I make for Shared Memory in ZeroMQ?

Tags: ipc, zeromq

I have a C application that get values from a sensor and a very high rate.
I want to make a Python code to retrieve only the latest value from my C application only when the Python code requests.

I was thinking about using Shared Memory for this purpose. But I don't see any example in ZeroMQ's website.

I'm new to ZeroMQ. I don't know if that's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about essentially using ZMQ as the vehicle to store to and retrieve from a shared memory space between two separate processes?  If so, then you're digging into details that aren't available to you in ZMQ.  Generally speaking, in your situation you would use the "IPC" connection protocol, and ZMQ makes the decision of how to store, send and retrieve that message on your system.

I haven't looked into the low level details of how it might opt to do this in any given scenario, I don't expect it to use shared memory, but it might.  Either way, I'm not aware of any way to force ZMQ to behave this way.